# How to avoid tables from being wrapped up while printing MATLAB command window to text file?

Tags: matlab, printing

I'm using a MATLAB program that prints a few wide tables (15 rows) to the MATLAB command window. Since the window is smaller, MATLAB splits the tables into two parts. At the end of the programs, the output is printed to a text file. Consequently, also, the text file shows the split version of the tables. Is there a way to print the full tables in both the command window and text file?

I'm using the mprint funtion (Econometric toolbox, James LeSage, http://www.spatial-econometrics.com/).

Comment: can you specify what command/function you are using to print to a text file? you should be able preserve the structure of your Matrix.

Comment: mprint of James LeSage's economeric toolbox

Comment: I suggest a structured data write, something like `csvwrite` should preserve all the structure. Also, the reason it does not fit on your Matlab Command window is because it is too small to fit everything; you could try inverting your data and see if it fits the other way round (by using the ' notation).

Comment: I edited your question and removed the `mprint` documentation since I'm not sure the code and documentation are in the public domain.